# How to configure YES or NO option inside custom teams tab for a bot?

Tags: c#, microsoft-teams, botframework

I have created a simple bot and deployed to teams.
I have also created a custom tab.
But I don't know how to integrate a YES or NO option( perhaps a dropdown) inside this tab.
By choosing yes or no I would want to customize the functionality of my bot.
Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The tab itself is simply an embedded webpage, so you could make it do whatever you like, provided you have (or have access to) basic web site development skills. In a backend API, you would save relevant settings for the user in a database, and the bot can be configured to read the settings from that database. The bot has access to the Activity object on the turncontext, which has a "From" property, which indicates who sent the message. On there is an AadObjectId (or "Azure AD unique object ID for this user"), which you can similarly get on your tab through the Teams `Context` (see more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/access-teams-context)) in order to save the settings for the relevant user.